# Probability that two Gaussian integers are divisible

Tags: probability, number-theory, ring-theory

Let $z = x+ iy \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ and let $a+ib \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ with $a^2 + b^2 \equiv 1 \mod{4}$. What is the probability that $a+ib$ divides $x + iy$ in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$? This question would resolve my answer to the probability that two gaussian integers are coprime as I asked here:

[Probability that $x \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346734/probability-that-x-equiv-3-pmod4-and-the-gaussian-integers)

Since I know from an answer on that thread that the probability that $p \equiv 1 \mod{4}$ is $1/3 = 1/|\left(\mathbb{Z} / 4\mathbb{Z}\right)^{\times}|$, I could also just ask the probability that any two arbitrary gaussian integers are divisible and then multiply that answer by $1/3$.

Comment: Shouldn't the probability be zero, unless you put a bound on $a$ and $b$?

Comment: @ZevChonoles: I'm not sure, care to explain?

Comment: Given any fixed $x+iy\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$, it only has finitely many divisors, while $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is infinite.

Comment: @ZevChonoles In the ring of integers ${\cal O}_K$ of a number field $K$, an integer is divisible by $n\in{\cal O}$ iff $x\equiv0$ in ${\cal O}/(n)$, so we may speak of $n\mid x$ happening with probability $|{\cal O}/(n)|^{-1}=N(n)^{-1}$ (which would be $1/(a^2+b^2)$ here, regardless of what $a^2+b^2$ is mod 4). My answer to the linked question covers this ground, but could benefit from more detail.

Comment: @anon: I think the problem was that it's not sufficiently clear from the question that $a+\mathrm ib$ is fixed and $x+\mathrm iy$ is "asymptotically uniformly" random; one could read the question the other way around (and I suspect that Zev did).